# Can you omit the "it"

Tags: subjects

Can the "it" be omitted in this sentence?

> It looks like quite the mess.

> Looks like quite the mess.

Comment: Not in formal communication, but in informal communication, it can. The omitted "it" is still there but just goes unsaid, remaining implied. An example from pop culture would be the title of the Nirvana song "Smells Like Teen Spirit," a title that is also a sentence that means "[It] smells like teen spirit."

Answer (score -1):

The second sentence is certainly more colloquial, and is perhaps not the best English. To native English speakers 'it' is simply understood in the second example, though to non-natives this may be a bit confusing.

I guess the second example could be a bit more vague in terms of what is in a mess, but any difference is marginal.

Comment: In any case 'quite the (something)' is a colloquial, and mainly North American way, of saying 'very much a (something)'.